# Proving that two matrices are congruent, in order to establish a rank and signature result.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I'm reading *Further Linear Algebra* by by T. S. Blyth, E. F. Robertson.  I'm somewhat stuck on Problem 9.14.  In particular, they want us to establish that the quadratic form
$$
Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{r < s} (x_r - x_s)^2
$$
has both rank and signature equal to $n-1$.  The hint they give us is to show that the matrix for $Q$ with respect to the standard basis has $n-1$ on the diagonal, and $-1$ elsewhere.  Then they ask us to show that this matrix is congruent to the diagonal matrix with entries $n-1, n-2, \ldots, 2, 1, 0$. I'm assuming there is some clever basis transformation that gives us $P^t A P = \text{diag}(n-1, n-2, \ldots, 2, 1, 0)$, but I can't figure it out.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a suggestion on how to do it more easily.

The all-$1$'s matrix $J$ has eigenvalues: $n$ once, $0$ with multiplicity $(n-1)$.

Hence $nI-J$ has eigenvalues $0$ once and $n$ with multiplicity $(n-1)$.

So the rank and signature are both $n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to note that for any $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$
$Q\big(\mathbf x\big) = Q\big(x_1,\ldots,x_n\big) = \sum_{r < s} (x_r - x_s)^2\geq 0$
so this is a positive semi-definite form.

If we select $\mathbf x:= \mathbf 1$ we get
$Q\big(\mathbf 1\big)= \sum_{r < s} (0)^2=0$
so the ones vector is in the nullspace  (this follows because the form is PSD).

---

*alternerative justification:*
explicitly writing out the bilinear form
$\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf 1\rangle $
$= \frac{1}{2}\Big(q\big(\mathbf x + \mathbf 1\big) - q\big(\mathbf 1,\mathbf 1\big) - q\big(\mathbf x,\mathbf x\big)\Big) $
$= \frac{1}{2}\Big(q\big(\mathbf x + \mathbf 1\big) - 0 - q\big(\mathbf x,\mathbf x\big)\Big) $
$=\frac{1}{2}\Big\{\Big(\sum_{r < s} \big((x_r+1) - (x_s+1)\big)^2\Big)-\Big(\sum_{r < s} \big(x_r - x_s\big)^2\Big)\Big\}$
$=\frac{1}{2}\Big\{\Big(\sum_{r < s} \big(x_r - x_s\big)^2\Big)-\Big(\sum_{r < s} \big(x_r - x_s\big)^2\Big)\Big\}$
$=0$
where the choice of $\mathbf x$ is arbitrary $\implies \mathbf 1$ is a null vector for the bilinear form.

---

Now for any $\mathbf x$ that is linearly independent of $\mathbf 1$ i.e. for any $\mathbf x \not\propto \mathbf 1$ we have
$Q\big(\mathbf x\big) = \sum_{r < s} (x_r - x_s)^2\gt 0$
since there is at least some pairing $x_r \neq x_s$.

This proves the form's signature is $\big(n-1,0\big)$ -- and Sylvester's Law of Inertia tells you this holds irrespective of how you select your matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing the pattern they want. You may use Sylvester's Law of Inertia for  any diagonal outcome.

You may get all integers (if it is alright to use $P$ with determinant larger than $1$) by multiplying on both right and left by diagonal $(1,n-1, n-2, ...3,2,1)$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
4 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 4 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 4 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 4 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 15 }{ 4 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 10 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
5 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 5 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 5 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 5 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 5 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 24 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!  Just by brute force algebra, I figured out that if you want to turn
$\sum_{i=1}^n (n-1)x_i^2 - 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}x_ix_j$ into $(n-1)y_1^2+(n-2)y_2^2+\cdots + 1 \cdot y_{n-1}^2 + 0\cdot y_n^2$, then using $y_k = \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k+1}}\left(x_k - \frac{x_{k+1}+\cdots+x_n}{n-k}\right)$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n-1$ and $y_n = x_n$, does the trick.  Again, I don't know what the pedagogical purpose of this exercise was.